# How to make certificate trusted and valid for more than one year

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, cyber-ark

I am using the following command to create certificate and this certificate will be used in window application. This certificate we need to validate application for cyberark security tool.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.companyname.com", "www.companyname.com" -CertStoreLocatio "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Type "CodeSigningCert" -Subject "Application Name" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature"
```

By using above command, I am able to create certificate.

**Problem:**

1.When I am looking into the installed certificate, it is showing:

[image]

2.It also show only one year valid date. How I can increase the valid date range more than one year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self-signed certificates aren't considered trustworthy unless you tell machines to trust them. Because cybercreeps.

To make your self-signed certificate trusted by a Windows machine, you must import it into the Trusted Root Certification Authority / Certificates location in the machine's certificate store. There are plenty of tutorials out there to walk you through this. Look for "How to install a self-signed certificate on Windows".

For the validity duration problem: Add `-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)` to your command line if you want a self-signed certificate good for ten years.

[Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-7).